# How to split column of data by "-" + any letter that follows? Keep the numbers that exist before it

Tags: excel, vba

So I have data like this:

[image]

The goal is to iterate through the values, and find the "-" that occurs right before any text. Once we find it, we remove the "-" + any text that occurs after, keeping the numbers and the other "-" between them.

I tried `=EXTRACTNUMBERS(A2,TRUE)` but it still didn't work. Any ideas? thanks you.

**EDIT:** The first two entries should yield **c-105-018-110-061-113** and **c-110-419-002** the letters in the first part of the sku should be ignored. I'm sorry I should've mentioned that.

Comment: Read up on the VBA method 'Split'

Comment: Please post a mock-up of the result you want. It sounds like the first 2 entries should both yield "105-018-110-061-113", but it's not clear.

Comment: The first two entries should yield `c-105-018-110-061-113` the letters in the first part of the sku should be ignored. I'm sorry I should've mentioned that.

Comment: _keeping the numbers_  Should `c-110-419-002-rs2` yield `c-110-419-002-2` or `c-110-419-002` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) is your friend. It splits a string into pieces.

Now all you have to do is loop over the pieces (I call them token) and look for the first non-numerical token. Start your loop at the 2nd token (this has index 1 as the result of split is a 0-based array) because you always want to include the first token.

After finding the first unwanted token (or reaching the end), remove the unwanted tokens by resizing the array and use the [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function)-function to glue the pieces together.

You can use the following function as UDF or in a routine that loops over you data.

```
Function specialSplit(s As String) As String
    Const SEPARATOR = "-"
    Dim tokens
    tokens = Split(s, SEPARATOR)
    If UBound(tokens) = 0 Then  ' No hyphen: Return the original string
        specialSplit = s
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Search for first Non-numeric token
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(tokens)
        If Val(tokens(i)) = 0 Then Exit For
    Next
    ' Resize array and return the joined pieces
    ReDim Preserve tokens(0 To i - 1)
    specialSplit = Join(tokens, SEPARATOR)
End Function
```

Comment: This assumes no `-000-` anywhere

Comment: It doesn't take any arguments right? Would I just run the function on cell A2?

Comment: If your data is in Col A, you could use the function as UDF and write for example `=specialSplit(A2)` to B2. This leaves Col A intact. If you want to overwrite the data in Col A, write a small VBA sub that loops over all cells in Col A, call the function and write returned value in to the cell, eg `cell.Value = specialSplit(cell.Value)` - but in that case your original value is gone forever.

Comment: @CDP1802 - True. And it also would not handle cases where a token starts with a digit and contains characters later.  You can easily adapt the code to make it more secure, I just wanted to show the idea.

Comment: @FunThomas Though of course `Split` is a logical *friend*, you might be interested in my `FilterXML` solution, too which I'm demonstrating for sheer *fun* :+)

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Excel 365, try this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(LET(items,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-
     "),REDUCE("",items,LAMBDA(str,item,IF(ISERR(1*item),str,str&" "&item)))))," 
     ","-")
```

Explanation:
Let's take a simple example: AAA-123-456

1. TextSplit splits the code into its individual items:

   AAA

   123

   456
2. Those three items are assigned to the internal name "items"
3. REDUCE runs through each item in items and passes each item through the LAMBDA function
4. The LAMBDA function checks each item, if it is numerical, it appends it to the internal variable called "str", if not, it leaves "str" unchanged
5. Once all items have been processed we end up with a space-delimited string:
   " 123 456"
6. The TRIM gets rid of the leading space:
   "123 456"
7. SUBSTITUTE replaces the spaces with dashes:
   "123-456"

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have 365 ... sorry. Is there a way in regular 2013 excel? Thanks

Comment: Nicely done; think however that not so experienced users would be grateful for a few hints on how to understand this udf. *btw seems that OP wants to keep the prefixed `c-` token.* @jkpieterse

Comment: I've added an explanation

Answer (score 2):

**VBA alternative via `FilterXML()`**

You may profit from an **XPath** search executed upon a wellformed **xml** code string (see section a) via the following search expression (see section b):

```
   "//i[.*0=0 or position()=1]
```

to get **all** numeric tokens *(as well as the very first token if i understand OP correctly)*

You need only some cosmetics to the XMLFilter result to join and transform it to the wanted code output (see section c).

```
Function adjustCode(ByVal s, Optional ErrorResult As String = "") As String
Const DELIM As String = "-"
'a) get well-formed xml string (temporary 9-prefix for num tokens)
    Dim xml As String
    xml = "<x><i>" & Replace(s, "-", "</i><i>9") & "</i></x>"
'b) execute XPath search upon xml
    Dim result
    result = Application.FilterXML(xml, "//i[.*0=0 or position()=1]")
'c) provide for correct xml result by checking var types
    Select Case VarType(result)
        Case vbError        ' non-findings (Error 2015)
            adjustCode = ErrorResult
        Case Is >= vbArray  ' 2-dim results (if more than 1 element)
            adjustCode = Join(Application.Transpose(result), DELIM)
            adjustCode = Replace(adjustCode, "-9", "-") ' remove temp 9-prefixes
        'Case Else          ' single element (here: digit)
    End Select
End Function
```

**Note** that Excel would cut numeric values starting with `0` like e.g. `018` to only `18`; therefor i used a tricky workaround by temporary prefixing each numeric value by an extra `9` which will be removed finally by replacing each `-9` splitter by delimiter `-` only.

**Side note**: *FilterXML is already available since Excel vers. 2013*

Comment: Very interesting approach. Thanks!